# How I can change the position of 3 div's to be side by side?

Tags: html, css

how I can change the position of 3 div's to be side by side?

Here's my HTML Code:

```
    <body>
    <div class="div_header" id="div_header"></div>
    <div class="div_left" id="div_left"></div>
    <div class="div_main" id="div_main"></div>
    <div class="div_right" id="div_right"></div>
    </body>
```

Here's my CSS Code of the 3 Div's:

```
.div_header {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}

.div_left {
    float: left;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
}

.div_main {
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 250px;
}

.div_right {
    float: right;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange your markup with the right-floated div before the main div

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/JwpEh/1/)**

```
<div class="div_header" id="div_header"></div>
<div class="div_left" id="div_left"></div>
<div class="div_right" id="div_right"></div>
<div class="div_main" id="div_main"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting. Why does the order in which you process them matter if the widths are all sized appropriately?

Answer (score 2):

You can use css "calc" to control your main div's width than add float:left on it.

```
.div_main {
    float: left;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: calc(100% - 500px);  <-- 250px+250px(div-left's width + div-right's width)
    background-color: blue;
}
```

here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/creed88/ucKw7/

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float: left;` to .div_main

Comment: thank you, and how i can make the .div_main 100% width?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left;` to `.div_main` or rearrange the div's.

If you don't have to use a float based layout, you can change the div's to be inline-block.

Div's are block level elements by default, and if you want things to be inline you need to change the display property.

Maybe the css below will work for you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2sd2J/)

```
.div_left,
.div_main,
.div_right {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WORKING DEMO -> [CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/kSK2u/1/)

add a class `.divpull` and add `float:left` to the class :)